# INNER JOIN SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

the next sql statement work fine. it shows both patient_id and serv_name, but i try to show patient_name instead of patient_id

```
SELECT  C1.patient_id, S.serv_name
FROM
    Checkup_Details C
    INNER JOIN Services S ON (C.serv_id=S.serv_id),
    Checkup C1
WHERE
    C1.today = DATE() AND C1.check_id=C.check_id
ORDER BY C.check_id
```

so how am i suppose to do that by adding this sql statement

```
INNER JOIN Patient P ON (C1.patient_id=P.patient_id)
```

but i don't know how exactely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the field patient_name is in Checkup_Details, you have to put

```
SELECT C1.patient_name ...
```

instead from

```
SELECT C1.patient_id ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the INNER JOIN clause to get the columns of the table Patient and change C1.patient_id by P.patient_name.

```
SELECT P.patient_name, S.serv_name
FROM
    Checkup_Details C
    INNER JOIN Services S ON (C.serv_id=S.serv_id),
    INNER JOIN Patient P ON (C1.patient_id=P.patient_id)
    Checkup C1
WHERE
    C1.today = DATE() AND C1.check_id=C.check_id
ORDER BY C.check_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix implicit and explicit `join` syntax.  A simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause:

```
SELECT C1.patient_id, S.serv_name
FROM Checkup_Details C  INNER JOIN
     Services S
     ON C.serv_id = S.serv_id INNER JOIN
     Checkup C1
     ON C1.check_id = C.check_id INNER JOIN
     Patient P
     ON C1.patient_id = P.patient_id
WHERE C1.today = DATE()
ORDER BY C.check_id;
```